# Use text instead of marker in nokia HERE map

Tags: here-api

I want to use text instead of StandardMarker in Nokia HERE map.

I tried using TextMarker but didn't work. May be I used incorrectly. Can you suggest me that how to do this?

Comment: Are you using 2.5.x or 3.0? I guess 2.5.x just want to make sure...

Answer (score 0):

TextMarker is not a built-in class of the API, rather the example in the API playground (http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/public/api-for-js/markers/extending-marker-to-text-marker.html) introduces this class by extending the Marker class. Take a look at the source code of the API explorer example.

The general idea is that you will need to produce a graphics (or graphics image) for the marker icon to use. There are multiple ways to do this but creating an SVG markup string with text is probably the easiest way to do it (as shown in the example code).

What the code in the example does it takes some variables and replaces parts of the SVG template string with the values.

```js
var iconSVG = '<svg width="__WIDTH__" height="__HEIGHT__" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<rect x="__X__" y="__Y__" rx="5" ry="5" width="__RECT_WIDTH__" height="__RECT_HEIGHT__" ' +
  'style="fill:__BRUSH__;stroke:__STROKE__;stroke-width:__STROKEWIDTH__;"/>' +
  '<text x="__OFFSETX__" y="__OFFSETY__" fill="__TEXT_PEN__" style="font-weight:normal; ' +
  'font-family:__FONTFAMILY__; font-size:__FONTSIZE__;" textContent="__TEXT__">__TEXT__</text>' +
  '</svg>',
```

From the SVG markup string you can produce a graphics image:

```js
icon = new nokia.maps.gfx.GraphicsImage(that.svgParser.parseSvg(iconSVG));
```

And this graphics image can be used as a marker icon.

```js
marker.set("icon", icon)
```

The most important thing to note is that you need to figure out the size of your text (width and height) manually.